# Android on touch events not detecting after scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout, android-view, android-debug

I am facing problem during detecting touch events. Its working fine without scrolling. But after scroll finished when I am removing finger not able to receive motion up event.I am using following code.

```
linearMain.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    // Do Something
                    Log.d("Touch", "Touch down");

                    // Now Set your animation
                    slidingDrawerMos.startAnimation(slideOutAnimation);
                     slidingDrawerReviews.startAnimation(slideOutAnimation);

                    slidingDrawerMos.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    slidingDrawerReviews.setVisibility(View.GONE);

                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                    // Do Something
                    Log.d("Touch", "Touch move");
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                    // Do Something
                    Log.d("Touch", "Touch up");
                    slidingDrawerMos.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                    slidingDrawerReviews.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                    // Now Set your animation
                    slidingDrawerMos.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
                    slidingDrawerReviews.startAnimation(slideInAnimation);
                    break;

                case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                    Log.d("Touch", "Touch cancel");
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 1):

```
your_control.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod());
```

and

```
 findViewById(R.id.your_control).getParent()
                            .requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(false);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I am unable to set linear.setMovementMethod(new ScrollingMovementMethod()). Please help me.

Comment: ok it not for linear layout.. it for underlying widget.. ok can you post xml?

Comment: which xml you want. Its normal xml. Just I am finding linear layout object then assigning touch event to that.